# Do something when InstallShield package uninstalls and in silent mode

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I have a package A which among other packages are part of another bigger package.

When A gets called second time - "setup.exe /S /Verbose Setup.exe.log" the uninstall occurs which is unwanted.

I want to return ResultCode=0 when A is being installed second time and is in silent mode.

How can I do this?

Thanks,

Comment: Does package A implement the OnMaintUIBefore() and OnMaintUIAfter() event handlers?

Comment: Yes! I tried to do "if MSICONDITION_TRUE = MsiEvaluateCondition(hMSI, "reinstall<>\"\"") then
    return 0;
endif;" inside setup.rul OnFirst OnFirstUIBefore() but still '-3' was returned on the second install.